# Unix AWK character searching

Tags: bash, unix, awk, scripting

If I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
chrY    14612243    1/1 8/8   0 12  DYS389I   4
chrY    14612243    1/1 8/8   0 12  DYS389I   4
chrY    14612243    1/1 8/8   0 29  DYS389B.2 4
chrY    14612243    1/1 8/8   0 29  DYS389B.2 4
chrY    7730432     1/1 -3/-3 0 20  DYS520    4
chrY    7730432     1/1 -3/-3 0 20  DYS520    4
```

How would I write an awk command that can help me extract the fourth column and split at the '/', getting me 8 8 or -3 -3

I tried doing

```
awk -F "/" '{print $3 " " $4}'
```

But it keeps printing the wrong columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below awk command,

```
$ awk '{split($4,a,"/"); print a[1],a[2]}' file
8 8
8 8
8 8
8 8
-3 -3
-3 -3
```

It splits the fourth column using the delimiter `/`, and stores it into an array. `a[1]` refers to the first splitted value and `a[2]` contains the second value.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use `space` and `/` as field separators:

```
awk -F '[ \t/]*' '{ print $5, $6 }' file
```

Output:

```
8 8
8 8
8 8
8 8
-3 -3
-3 -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another choice:

```
awk '{sub("/", " ", $4); print $4}' file
```